# How to get request headers in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I writing code for authorization. After click on the button for login I create a new header with

```
res.header('Authorization', token)
```

admin_login router:

```
router.post('/admin_login', async (req, res) => {
    const adminDB = data.admins;
    const admin = adminDB.find(admin => req.body.email === admin.email)
    if (!admin) return res.status(400).send('Email in not found!')
    if (admin.password !== req.body.password) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password')
    const token = jwt.sign({ admin }, 'the_secret_key')
    res.header('Authorization', token)
    res.redirect('/admin')
})
```

I wont to recieve Authorization header after login in admin router, but I wont recieve it. I see Authorization header in

Code for verification:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('Authorization')
    console.log(token)

    if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Access Denied')

    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, 'the_secret_key')
        req.admin = verified
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid token')
    }
}
```

first img: headers in admin router

second img: headers in admin_login router after click on the button for login

[image]

[image]

Please, help me

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell from the documentation, there is no `header` method on the Express [`Request`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object or the Node.js [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) it extends.

The Express documentation says that to retrieve a header, you use [`get`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get):

> **`req.get(field)`**
>
> Returns the specified HTTP request header field (case-insensitive match).

So:

```
const token = req.get("Authorization");
```

Or you could use the [`headers` object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers) from `IncomingMessage`:

```
const token = req.headers["authorization"];
```

(Note the lower case, Node.js makes the header names lower case when building the object.)

Comment: I wrote it, but still not getting a Authorization header.

Comment: @AliceArgent - I'm unclear on what your various pieces are. You've said you're *setting* the header on the response, but you're also expecting to see it on a request? You'll only see it on the request if the requester sends it.

Comment: I didn't knew it. Thanks, you) Perhaps, I understand my error. I'll try to send header in code for verification.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `req.get(headerName)` method